# Make audio work on all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, audio

I've been testing a web app and for some reason lots of the audio that should play onLoad fails to play in many cases. Is there a better strategy to ensure audio plays on all devises/ browsers?

Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
}
});
```

HTML:

```
 <audio id="audio1" src="https://LINK.wav" ></audio>
```

Comment: I edited to include #audio1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited based on comment feedback -thanks!)

Wave files are uncompressed audio and tend to be really large files that need to be downloaded. This is why Mp3, Ogg, or AAC are preferred as web formats. Not all browsers support each one though. Firefox doesn't support AAC, and IE and Safari don't support Ogg. You can use [caniuse to check](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio).

HTML5 audio would be set up like:

```
<audio controls preload>
  <source src="https://LINK.m4a" type="audio/mp4" />
  <source src="https://LINK.oga" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Information from [this article on HTML5 audio types](https://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, that makes sense! I edited my answer to include some more information- though I think the other response was a better answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the file type, like

```
 <audio id="audio1" src="your_filepath/LINK.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

But if you only supply a WAV file, some browsers won't be able to play it (like IE)

It's more reliable to supply mp3 *and* ogg files, like this:

```
<audio>
  <source src="LINK.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="LINK.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

At least one of these two is understood by every browser, and the (compressed) files are much smaller, so it won't take that long until they load and start to play.